# Que es <function StatefulBrowser.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x00000295B80ECF70> al utilizar mechanicalsoup?

Tags: python, scraping

estoy intentando hacer web scraping en una intranet que requiere log in por lo que estoy utilizando mechanicalsoup para lograr entrar pero al momento de verificar si efectivamente pude entrar a la pagina utilizo print(browser.follow_link) lo cual me retorna <function StatefulBrowser.**init**.. at 0x00000295B80ECF70>. luego quiero moverme a otra pagina dentro de esta utilizando browser.follow_link("materials"), lo cual me cambia ese codigo recien puesto por lo que creeria que estoy dentro pero al momento de intentar utilizar beautifulsoup me dice que estoy todavia en la pagina principal sin haber iniciado sesion

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*','Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET','Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type','Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600','User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'}

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open("https://oligrafic.twistsoftware.com/d/users/sign_in")
browser.select_form('form[action="/d/users/sign_in"]')
browser["user[rut]"]= "username"
browser["user[password]"]= "password"
browser.submit_selected()

browser.follow_link("materials")

print(browser.get_url)
# aqui finaliza el uso de mechanical -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#print(browser.get_url)

#url = browser.url
#req = requests.get(url, headers)
#soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
#print("llegue hasta aqui")
#print(soup.prettify()) ```
````

Comment: Lo que se te muestra es la definición de la clase. Lo mismo ocurre si creas una clase e imprimes `print(clase)` (sin parentesis al poner la clase)

Comment: @Christian, muchas gracias. Entonces me parece que si deberia funcionar pero funciona solo algunas veces y no entiendo por que. Si cierro y abro vsc funciona una primera vez pero si vuelvo a correr el codigo ya no es capaz de ingresar el login y queda pegado en la primera url. Ademas tendras alguna manera de proceder luego para extraer informacion de divs dentro de un table? muchas gracias de ante mano